# How to connect HapiJs to Swagger?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I am trying to connect Hapijs to the swagger project. I am currently using this package

[Hapi Swagger](https://github.com/glennjones/hapi-swagger)

Here is my code:

```
const Inert = require('inert');
const Vision = require('vision');
server.register([
    Inert,
    Vision,
    {
        'register': require('hapi-swagger'),
        'options': options
    }
], (err) => {
    server.start((err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
        }
    });
});
```

I got this error message

```
  if (plugin.register.register) {                             // Required plugin
                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'register' of undefined
```

dependencies

```
 "hapi": "^16.6.2",
 "hapi-swagger": "^8.0.0",
```

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 1):

I have implement hapi swagger like this hope this will work for you.

```
'use strict';

const HapiSwagger = require('hapi-swagger');
const Inert = require('inert');
const Vision = require('vision');
const Config = require('config');
const DatabaseSetting = Config.get('DatabaseSettings');

//Register Swagger
const Pack = require('../package');

exports.register = (server, options,next) => {  
    server.register([
        Inert,
        Vision,
        {
            'register': HapiSwagger,
            'options': {
                'info': {
                    'title': `API Documentation for  ${DatabaseSetting.env} environment`,
                    'version': Pack.version,
                    //'description':'Please use "accept :application/vnd.easyme.version.v1+json" for api versioning'
                },
                 'schemes': ['http'],
                'pathPrefixSize':2,
                'basePath': '/',
                documentationPath:'/doc',
                debug:true
            }
        }], (err) => {
        if (err) {
            server.log(['error'], `hapi-swagger load error: ${err}`)
        }else{
            server.log(['start'], 'hapi-swagger interface loaded')
        }
    });
    next();
};

exports.register.attributes = {
    name: 'swagger-plugin'
};
```

and on `server.js` i have import file and register like this

```
// Register All Plugins
server.register(Plugins, err => {
  if (err) {
    server.error(`Error while loading plugins : ${err}`)
  } else {
    server.log('info', 'Plugins Loaded')
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a separate file for swagger plugin registration. You can add the similar file and just need to pass the server context to register the plugin.

You can remove the Winston and Raven (Sentry.io) in case if you not using those in your project.

Snippet from **package.json**

```
"hapi": "^16.6.2",
"hapi-swagger": "^8.0.0",
"inert": "^4.2.1",
"vision": "^4.1.1",
```

**hapi-swagger.js**

```
/**
 * Embeds Hapi-Swagger plugin to the server
 */

/* jslint node: true */
/* jshint esversion: 6 */

'use strict';

const Inert = require('inert');
const Vision = require('vision');
const Winston = require('logger/WinstonPlugin');
const Raven = require('errors/RavenPlugin');
const environment = require('config').environment;
const port = require('config').port;

const swaggerOptions = {
    info: {
        title: 'API Documentation - [' + environment + ':' + port + ']'
    },
    tags: [{
        name: 'user',
        description: 'Related to User Object'
    }, {
        name: 'email',
        description: 'For verification of User Email'
    }, {
        name: 'session',
        description: 'Session Management'
    }, {
        name: 'account',
        description: 'User Account'
    }],
    jsonEditor: true,
    grouping: 'tags',
    securityDefinitions: {
        Bearer: {
            type: 'apiKey',
            name: 'Authorization',
            in: 'header',
            "scopes": {
                "write:pets": "modify pets in your account",
                "read:pets": "read your pets"
            }
        }
    }
};

/**
 * Registers Swagger Plugin in Hapi Server object
 * @param {*} server - Hapi.Server
 */
function RegisterSwaggerPlugin(server) {

    if (!server) return;

    server.register([Inert, Vision,
        {
            register: require('hapi-swagger'),
            options: swaggerOptions
        }
    ], function (err) {
        if (err) {
            Winston.error(['error'], 'hapi-swagger load error: ' + err);
            Raven(err);

        } else {
            Winston.debug('hapi-swagger interface loaded');
        }
    });
}

module.exports = RegisterSwaggerPlugin;
```

You can register the plugin from your server.js file like this.

**server.js**

```
// Add Swagger Plugin here
require('plugin-registration/hapi-swagger')(server);
```

So this way anytime you want to block the plugin registration you can just do it by commenting single line.